# How can I repeat a video at slow playback speed?

Tags: video, quicktime

Is there any way to repeat a video while it's playing in slow motion?

I tried using both QuickTime and VLC. I don't see a way to control the playback speed in QuickTime, and the problem with VLC is that when the video replays, it loses the playback speed setting.

Comment: VLC should be able to do this.  Have you tried to choose "Slower" from the "Playback" menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with QuickTime 7. Grab a copy off the Mac OS X Install DVD.

Go Window-> AV Controls and change the playback speed. (Or something with a similar name)

Then View-> Loop for repeating.

Comment: This works. The only problem is that the slowest it can go is 1/2 speed.

Answer (score 1):

Option-clicking the forward button increases playback speed by 0.1. Clicking the backward button plays videos in reverse though. You can set the rate between 0 and 1 by running this in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player" to set rate of document 1 to 0.8
```

In [Movist](http://code.google.com/p/movist/) you can press ⇧⌘← or adjust the slider in the control HUD.